# Changing the color of a text box depending on its content

Tags: c++, winforms, textbox, colors

I have in a VS2005 C++ Form application a table adapter and a Text box that displays data from a specific column. What I want to do is to have its color changed on whether the content is >0 or <0. I tried adding this:

```
if(this->CSumTextBox->TabIndex<0) 
{
    this->CSumTextBox->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
}
```

But it doesn't work... (I didn't really believe TabIndex was the correct function, but it seemed the only one close)
Help please

Edit: CSum is a double.
Here is the whole code for CsumTextBox:

```
// 
// CSumTextBox
// 
this->CSumTextBox->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Bottom | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Left));
this->CSumTextBox->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::Window;
this->CSumTextBox->DataBindings->Add((gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Binding(L"Text", this->sumclosedpnlBindingSource, L"CSum", true)));
this->CSumTextBox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(214, 632);
this->CSumTextBox->Name = L"CSumTextBox";
this->CSumTextBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(86, 20);
this->CSumTextBox->TabIndex = 7;
```

It is in the Form Header (the whole program is a GUI, so almost everything is in there...)

Edit: Maybe if I check the data binding source's Value it would work, but how can I do that?
(Does a `this->sumclosedpnlBindingSource->returnvalue(CSum)` or something like that exist?)

Comment: Is CSumTextBox the actual variable name? It sounds more like a class name.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by this:

> … have its color changed on whether the content is >) …

To get access to the content of the text box, use its `Text` property. To test for a numeric value, you need to convert it to an integer (or other number type) first:

```
int value = System::Int32::Parse(CSumTextBox->Text);

if (value < 0)
    CSumTextBox->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
```

Comment: sorry meant >0 (typo...) I tried this, I also tried a small variation (double value = System::Double::Parse(this->CSumTextBox->Text); if (value < 0) {this->CSumTextBox->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;}) but it gives me a FormatExeption

Comment: Well, the `FormatException` clearly says that your `TextBox` doesn't contain a valid floating-point number.

Comment: If that's the case what could I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
int val = -1;
if(!Int32::TryParse(CSumTextBox->Text) || val != 0)
{
   CSumTextBox->ForeColor = System::Drawing::Color::Red;
}
```

This will check that the value in the textbox actually converts to an integer, and that the value is not 0.

Comment: You forgot a `%^val` as the second parameter to `TryParse`.

Comment: … what I meant was: a tracking reference … whatever the syntax for it (can't remember).

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but I never write managed C++ so I was just winging it.  :)